# How to write a one-liner with list comprehension that depends on comparing and storing values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have `lines = ["222,333", ...]`
How to rewrite following:

```py
res = 0
result = []
for line in lines:
   body, exp = line.split(',')
   logr = math.log(int(body), int(exp))
   if logr > res:
       res = logr
       result = [int(body), int(exp)]
```

into one-liner?

I am trying something like

```py
result = [math.log(int(d.split(',')[0]), int(d.split(',')[1])) for d in lines]
```

But after I do that, I'm stuck. How to compare my math.log to previous result and if it is bigger, write it to some variable?

I expect the output to be `"333,444"`, or something similar.

Comment: I think your original version is a lot clearer. LC isn't really the appropriate construct for reduce operations, IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one-liner for `result`, and a one-liner for `res`:

```
result = max([[*map(int,d.split(','))] for d in lines], key=lambda p: math.log(*p))
res = math.log(*result)
```

<sup>*tada*</sup>

What magic is this?

One point to realise is that `result` will end up being only one list of length two: `[body, exp]`. And this list is decided by `logr > res`—a ***key*** to sort by—implying the use of `min`, `sorted`, `max`, or similar.

The issue with immediately evaluating the log, as demonstrated in the attempt in the question, is that we lose the values obtained from `split(', ')`. But we need these values for `result`! Instead, keep the values, determine the correct pair first, and evaluate the log afterwards.

Now down to the one-liners. The first part of the comprehension is fairly straightforward.

```
[[*map(int,d.split(','))] for d in lines]
```

This creates a list of lists of parsed lines.

```
["111,222", "333,444", "555,666"]  # before (lines)
[[111, 222],
 [333, 444],
 [555, 666]]    # after (list comp.)
```

We then select the pair which has the *highest* log. In other words, we take the `max`, comparing by a key of `key=lambda p: math.log(*p)` (i.e. compare by the log).

(In case you were wondering what the asterisk does, it unpacks the given iterable (see [What does the star operator mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean?noredirect=1&lq=1) for more info). In this particular case, `math.log(*p)` is the same as `math.log(p[0], p[1])`.)

Once we've selected our result, we throw it into `math.log` again to compute `res`.

And all ends well.

Comment: That's..... wow. I didn't even think of inserting lambda function in list comprehension and then surround it with `max` argument! Thank you very much, I literally was stuck for more than day on that!